# How to extract customer information from an id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have got many customers with the same first name/last name. But, all customers have a specific id(OL_ID). My task is when I click one customer's OL_ID in port.php, it should take to example.php and extract the particular customer's information.

I tried this following code and they are not working. It says "enter the correct OL_ID again!" for all id's. I know there is some mistake in example.php. I would be grateful if someone corrects this.

port.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    //connect to DB
    ini_set('display_errors', 0); //<- here you can switch on and off the error reporting 0 / 1     
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $host = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = "mysqlr00tpa55";
    try
         { 
          $myconnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
          // set the PDO error mode to exception    
          $myconnection ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          //ECHO "TEST";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM OL_trans WHERE';
        if (!empty($_POST['vorname']))
        //Vorname
        {
            $sql .= ' vorname = ? AND ';
            $params[] =  $_POST['vorname'];
        }   
        if (!empty($_POST['nachname']))
        //Nachname
        {
            $sql .= ' nachname = ? AND ';
            $params[] =  $_POST['nachname'];
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['email']))
        //E-mail address
        {
            $sql .= ' email = ? AND ';
            $params[] =  $_POST['email'];
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['strasse']))
        //Strasse
        {
            $sql .= ' strasse = ? AND ';
            $params[] =  $_POST['strasse'];
        }
        if ( !empty($_POST['ort']) )
        //Ort
        {
            $sql .= ' ort= ? AND ';
            $params[] =  $_POST['ort'];
        }
        if ( !empty($_POST['plz']))
        //Plz
        {
            $sql .= ' plz= ? AND ';
            $params[] = $_POST['plz'];
        }
        if ( !empty($_POST['telefon']))
        //Telefonnummer
        {
            $sql .= ' telefon=? AND ';
            $params[] = $_POST['telefon'];
        }
        if( !empty($_POST['adrZus']))
        //HausnummerZusatz
        {
            $sql .= ' adrZus=? AND ';
            $params[] = $_POST['adrZus'];
        }
        if( !empty($_POST['hnr']))
        //Hausnummer
        {
            $sql .= ' hnr=? AND ';
            $params[] = $_POST['hnr'];
        }
         $sql = rtrim($sql, 'AND ');
         $stmt = $myconnection->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->execute($params);
         $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
         foreach($rows as $row)
         {
              ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Data fetched</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    body
    {
         background-image: url("background.gif");
         color:white;
         font-size:40px;
         font-family:"times new roman", times, serif;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <br/><br/><table align="center" border="3px" style="width:75%; line-height:40px; background-color:#616263">
                        <t>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Customer id</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Vorname</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Nachname</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Email Id</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Strasse</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Ort</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Plz</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Telefon</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Mobil</th>
                        </t>
    <tr align="center">                  
           <td style="cursor: pointer;">

              <a href="example.php"><?php echo $row['OL_ID']; ?></a></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['vorname'];?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['nachname'];?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['strasse'];?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['ort'];?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['plz'];?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['mobil'];?></td>
    </tr>   
    </table>
    </body>  
    </html>
    <?php
    } 
    }else
    {
         echo"Enter the correct information again!";
    }
     }
    catch(PDOException $e)
       {
         echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
         }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    </head>
    <style>
    button[type=button1]
        {
            border-radius: 40px 10px 35px 8px;
            width: 170px;height:60px;
            padding-left: 3px;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: 2px 1px;
            font-size: 28px;
            background-color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9);
            font-weight:bolder;
            }
    button[type=button1]:hover
      {
        background-image: url("background.gif");
        cursor: pointer;
        color: white;
        font-size:32px;
        box-shadow:2px 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <body>
    <br/>
    <button type="button1" onclick="goBack()"/>Zurück</button>
    <script>
    function goBack()
                    {
                      window.history.back();
                    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is example.php:

When I click OL-ID in port.php, it should extract the customer's information on selected OL_ID

```
    <?php
    //connect to DB
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); //<- here you can switch on and off the error reporting 0 / 1 - makes life easy ;) 
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //echo $_POST['vorname'];

    $debug=1;
                $host = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = "mysqlr00tpa55";
         try {
              $myconnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
              // set the PDO error mode to exception    
              $myconnection ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

               if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    $num=$_POST['OL_ID'];
                   $statement = $myconnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM OL_trans  WHERE OL_ID LIKE '$num' ");
                   $statement->execute();
                   $key = $statement->fetchall();
                   foreach($key as $value){ ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <title>Data fetched</title>
    </head>
    <style>
         body{
         background-image: url("background.gif");
         color: white;
         font-weight: bolder;
         font-size: 40px;
         font-family:  sans-serif serif cursive;
         padding-top: 105px;    }
    </style>
    <body>
                   <br/><br/><table align="center" border="3px" style="width:70%; line-height:80px; background-color:#616261">
                        <t>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Customer id</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Vorname</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Nachname</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Email Id</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Strasse</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Ort</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Plz</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Telefon</th>
                             <th style="color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9); font-size:25px">Mobil</th>
                        </t>
      <tr align="center">                  
           <td><?php echo $value['OL_ID']; ?></a></td>
           <td><?php echo $value['vorname']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value['nachname']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value['email']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value['strasse']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value['ort']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value['plz']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value['telefon']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value['mobil']; ?></td>
      </tr>   


</table>
</body>  
</html>
<?php
          }
          }
          else{
               echo "enter the corect OL_ID again!";
          }
     }
     catch(PDOException $e)
         {
           echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <style>
        button[type=button1]{
        border-radius: 40px 10px 35px 8px;
        width: 160px;height:55px;
        padding-left: 3px;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 2px 1px;
        font-size: 28px;
        background-color:rgba(238, 130, 7, 0.9);
        font-weight:bolder;
        }
        button[type=button1]:hover{
       background-image: url("background.gif");
        cursor: pointer;
        color: white;
        font-size:32px;
        box-shadow: 2px 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
     <br/>
  <button type="button1" onclick="goBack()"/>Zurück</button>
  <script>
     function goBack() {window.history.back();}
  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have this condition `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { ... }`. So check if `submit` is posted. The problem is pretty clear here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're missing a question mark (and a param name) in *port.php*. Change this:

```
<a href="example.php"><?php echo $row['OL_ID']; ?></a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="example.php?id=<?php echo $row['OL_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['OL_ID']; ?></a>
```

Secondly, access the now passed **id** param via `$_GET` in *example.php* instead of `$_POST`. Change this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $num=$_POST['OL_ID'];
```

to this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $num=$_GET['id'];
```

Thirdly, read about SQL injections regarding this line:

```
$statement = $myconnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM OL_trans  WHERE OL_ID LIKE '$num' ");
```